# How to word-break in horizontal list items using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a horizontal list and enable word-break inside li.

The example below outputs like this:

```
|---------element width---------|
abcdefghij ABCDEFGHIJ 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

This is what I want:

```
|---------element width---------|
abcdefghij ABCDEFGHIJ aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

I tried float left, other break-word css, specifying width or max-width, etc.

```css
li { display : inline-block; word-break : break-all; }
```

```html
            <ul>
                <li>abcdefghij</li>
                <li>ABCDEFGHIJ</li>
                <li>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: a small qeustion here...if there if a new li element after last<li>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</li> how it should appear

Answer (score 3):

So the solution is [here](http://codepen.io/radbrawler/pen/yVYObd)

You'll need to put the parent `<ul>` with `word-break: break-all` property which will break the child elements whenever they overflow. The child `<li>`elements needs to be set with `block: inline` property to make them appear in a line.

```css
ul {
  width: 250px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Word Break Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>abcdefghij</li>
    <li>ABCDEFGHIJ</li>
    <li>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the result what you want you will have to use `word-wrap: break-word`.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: The challenge is to make `li` elements start inline and wrap after element reached the border. See question. `word-wrap: break-word` won't suffice problems need.

Answer (score 0):

Word-wrap has 4 values :

`word-wrap: normal|break-word|initial|inherit;`

But in you example you have marked `display : inline-block;`

so `word-wrap:break-word` will work . Please implement that

Comment: li { display : inline-block; word-break : break-word; width: 100px; float:left; }

Comment: but each Li has its own block so it will wrap with in their specific LI block. I defined width and set float:left.